# How do I make my chrome notification clickable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications, onclick

I am trying to implement clickable functionality into my chrome notification, allowing it to open a url in a new tab, but nothing seems to working.

Tried adding multiple different variants of listeners, none of which seem to take.

```
function show() {
  var streamer = 'Streamer';
  var quote = 'Quote';
  new Notification(quote, {
    icon: 'assets/600x600.png',
    body: streamer + ' is live!',
    url: 'www.youtube.com'
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function show() {
  var streamer = 'Streamer';
  var quote = 'Quote';
  var test = new Notification(quote, {
    icon: 'assets/600x600.png',
    body: streamer + ' is live!',
    url: 'www.youtube.com'
  });
  test.onclick = function(){
      window.open('http://example.com');
      window.focus();
  };
}
```